# {"Cannot convert value"} error while save geometry data to postgresql table

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sharpmap, nettopologysuite

I want to add a record to postgresql table with DevArt dotConnect for PostgreSQL component. I use Entity Framework 6 and I add a kind of NuGet packages to my project. SharpMap, NetTopologySuite,GeoAPI...etc common geographic libraries for .net. But i get an error while saving data. Error is {"Cannot convert value"}. I can not solve this problem.

My Code

```
        using (var db = new MAKSDBDEVEntities())
        {
            var ilce = new MaksIlce()
            {
                Adi = "test",
                Guid = "hede",
                IlkKayitIp = "127.0.0.1",
                IlkKayitTarihi = DateTime.Now,
                IlkKayitKullaniciId = 0,
                UlkeGID = 1,
                Geom = DbGeometry.PointFromText("POINT(10 20)", 4326)
            };
            db.MaksIlces.AddObject(ilce);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```